# Django duplicating block.super content

Tags: django, templates, django-oscar

using in template inheritance as in the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/overriding-templates/#extending-an-overridden-template) I'm getting duplication as shown:

[image: google tag quotes duplicated]

In the above photo the commented Google Tag Manager text has been duplicated.  Obviously I would like to put the actual tag manager in there, but it's a simpler example for SO this way.  Anything I put in my child template tag is duplicated when I call `{{ base.super }}`  I'm using Oscar, so here's my inheritance scheme.

[oscar/base.html](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/master/src/oscar/templates/oscar/base.html)

```
#from oscar module
#relevent sections only

{% load i18n %}
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ LANGUAGE_CODE|default:"en-gb" }}" class="{% block html_class %}no-js{% endblock %}">
    <head>
        {% block tracking %}
            {# Default to using Google analytics #}
            {% include "oscar/partials/google_analytics.html" %}
        {% endblock %}
    </head>
```

my base override

```
# located in my procject at 'oscar/base.html'
{% extends 'oscar/base.html' %}

{% block tracking %}
    {{ block.super }}
    <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
    <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
{% endblock %}
```

Below is anything else I think could be involved.  Any troubleshooting tips that would help me debug this would be welcome.

my view

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView

class BaseTestView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "oscar/base.html"
```

urls.py

```
from myurls import BaseTestView
urlpatterns = [
    path('i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    
    path('base_test', BaseTestView.as_view(), name='base+test'),
    
    ##OSCAR###############################################################
    path('', include(apps.get_app_config('oscar').urls[0])),

    ##WAGTAIL#############################################################
    path('cms/', include(wagtailadmin_urls)),
    path('documents/', include(wagtaildocs_urls)),
    path('pages/', include(wagtail_urls)),
    
    
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) \
    + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

settings.py templates

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            location('templates'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                ####DEFAULT################################################
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',

                ####DEFAULT################################################
                # 'uniquesite.context_processors.metadata',
                
                ####OSCAR################################################
                'oscar.apps.search.context_processors.search_form',
                'oscar.apps.checkout.context_processors.checkout',
                'oscar.apps.communication.notifications.context_processors.notifications',
                'oscar.core.context_processors.metadata',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are simply extending your own template. It looks like you are using **Method 1** described in [How to customise templates](https://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/3.0a/howto/how_to_customise_templates.html) in Oscar's documentation which involves simply copying their templates and modifying them.
But you act like you are using **Method 2**.  I believe the simplest solution would be to just copy their template instead of extending it, or you can have a look into using Method 2 as described in their documentation where they use a parent directory trick. Or as an alternate option given in Method 2 use [django-overextends](https://github.com/stephenmcd/django-overextends).

Comment: I'm using Method 2.  I haven't copied any oscar templates.  I've tested and both your solutions will let me side step the problem. I agree there has to be a circular reference inherent here somewhere and I've thought as well that the template engine is extending my own template...  buy I want to know why.  The django docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/overriding-templates/#extending-an-overridden-template) show pretty much the exact scheme I'm using.  :(

Comment: As per your code `# located in my procject at 'oscar/base.html'` and `{% extends 'oscar/base.html' %}` your template is `oscar/base.html` and you are extending `oscar/base.html`. Does that not mean you are extending the same template. In method 2 they use a trick of a parent directory so you might need to instead `{% extends 'the_directory_above/oscar/base.html' %}`

Comment: @JamieMarshall can you try putting your `base.html` directly in your `templates` directory and not have an `oscar` directory does that work?

Comment: You bring up a good point, however override and extend works exactly as expected, until I call `{{ block.super }}`.  The 'trick' blog post is from 2008 and today django supports override and extend so I wonder how reliable that is.  I wonder if `extends` evaluates the correct template but `{{ block.super }}` doesn't navigate the `APP_DIRS`: True correctly...

Comment: I just tried your last test.  Putting `base.html` in my `templates` directory does in fact remove the duplication.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, which was caused by me including the template path twice in my settings `TEMPLATES` var.

For you it might be because you have both of the following settings. You probably can remove the first:

```
TEMPLATES = [
        ...
        'DIRS': [
            location('templates'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
         ...
]
```

When the template is included twice, the `extends 'oscar/base.html'` first imports `oscar/base.html` agaon from your own template dir, only then is the actual template included, but now we have two `{% block tracking %}` in the html.

Comment: Ha! We totally made this mistake. For reference, the Django docs [make it pretty clear](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/templates/#configuration) that `'APP_DIRS': True` is probably all you're going to need for a basic app with its own `appname/templates` directory, unless you're doing something _really_ tricky with templates.

Comment: One thing that confuses me, though, where's that `location()` coming from? Some function you defined in your `settings.py` that resolves something relative to your project root, like `Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent / "templates"` would do?